# найти пару с заданной суммой в массиве

Tags: python, python-3.x

нужна функция, которая принимает на вход массив `x` и число `y` и возвращает массив из двух элементов `x`, сумма которых равна `y`

получилось сделать подобную функцию с словарем, но мне именно нужно чтобы на выходе был массив

Comment: В простейшем случае два цикла проверяют все пары. Это подходит?

Comment: вопрос в чем - как переделать словарь, видимо, в список?

Comment: @MBo зачем два? Одного цикла достаточно. Проверять есть ли ``y - x[i]`` в списке

Comment: Нужно искать первую пару значений массива для которых сумма равна заданному `y`?

Comment: @Эникейщик Верно, хотя под капотом тоже самое произойдёт (плюс надо отсечь пары с собой же)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов:

```py
def func(x, y):
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(x)):
            if x[i] + x[j] == y:
                return [x[i], x[j]]
```

Comment: а можно ли сделать так чтобы возвращались индексы элементов? я попробовал так `return [nums.index([i])]` и у меня вышла ошибка ValueError: [0] is not in list

Comment: @miluvu увы, нельзя